# Change the score value of all users in a single query to 100 (one hundred)

Tags: python, django

```
class CUser(User):
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

Change the score value of all users in a single query to 100 (one hundred)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) the code below should work :

```
CUser.objects.all().update(score=100)
```

Comment: The .all() isn't necessary, but it does make the code's function very clear

Comment: I was not sure about .all() but I put it because the doc use it and because I agree it makes the code more clear.